# How to scale image aspect ratio in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I don't want to crop the image, I want to set aspect ratio.
Useful when fixing images stretched from 4:3 to widescreen resolutions, for example.

Answer (score 2):

image > scale image > image size ("open" chain)

You have to set resolution manually to match your aspect ratio of choice.